# Referencing the same project in two solutions causes building of the second solution to fail

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, mfc

I am getting an error while building a complex project on a TFS build server. I was able to reproduce the error with a simpler setup that I'll be using here to describe the problem. Due to the age and complexity, the project still uses the build tools of Visual Studio 2010.

I have a repository with two solutions: WindowsProject1 and WindowsProject2, which are both MFC applications.
I also added the project WindowsProjectTools to both solutions, because the dll is referenced by the main project in both.

The problem occurs when building the solutions on the build server like this:
[image]

The first build step (WindowsProject1) succeeds, but the second (WindowsProject2) fails with the following errors:

[image]

```
Error C1090: PDB API call failed, error code '23' : '(
```

There are some questions on the web about this error, but never with a satisfactory solution.

I suspected that building WindowsProjectTools in both build steps will collide for some reason, maybe the intermediate folder intersects, so I changed it to $(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\ but it did not help.

However, changing the build step order helps insofar that then building WindowsProject2 succeeds, but WindowsProject1 fails. This makes me believe that the solution and project files are in order, but that there is some setting in TFS that I am missing.

I have also tried to change MSBuild Version from Latest to 4.0 (the version associated with VS2010) without success.

Migrating to newer vs version is an obvious step. However, it would require massive ressources to migrate the entire project. I would like to avoid this step at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a bug report for a mostly similar problem in the Jenkins build server: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9104

The program mspdbsrv.exe seems unsuited for parallel builds. The workaround for jenkins was to change the temp dir:

```
_MSPDBSRV_ENDPOINT_=<UUID>
TMP=<Unique Tempdir>
TEMP=$TMP TMPDIR=$TMP
```

In another solution, the mspdbsrv was kept alive throughout the build process:

```
rem :: PITA to keep MSPDBSRV alive
set ORIG_BUILD_ID=%BUILD_ID%
set BUILD_ID=DoNotKillMe
start mspdbsrv -start -spawn
set BUILD_ID=%ORIG_BUILD_ID%
set ORIG_BUILD_ID=
```

(PITA stumped me at first, never heard of it, what new technology could this be!? Then I had a good laugh.)

Neither worked for us. In the latter the build server just started another instance of mspdbsrv.exe. We guessed that the server is started each time a new solution is built. Since there is little time between build steps (1/10th of a second), we surmised that the server program is not ready to be restarted so soon after its exit. The work around we implemented now is a powershell script build step inbetween solution build steps that waits 10 seconds until continuing:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
```

This gives mspdbsrv.exe ample time for shutdown and restart. The pdb api error does not occur anymore.

I realize it is merely another workaround, but we cannot afford to spend more time on this. Our main concern was, that our build artefacts are intact and in proper form, which was not the case with other solutions (such as /Z7 instead of /Zi). As such our workaround is superior.

Other situations that provoke the PDB API call failed, error code '23' may not be solved by this workaround, but my recommendation is to consider the behaviour of mspdbsrv.exe.